# Is it possible to open the terminal via a bookmark

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, mate

For my work, I have to travel a lot. This means I have to power down my laptop often. The downside of this it that is always takes some time after a clean power on to open all the terminals to continue my work where I left.

Is there such thing as *terminal bookmarks*? It would be ideal if I could bookmark the state of the terminal, meaning that all tabs, the order of tabs, their title, their *up key history* (usually I  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>  a running application, do some debugging elsewhere, press the  <kbd>up</kbd>  key and then  <kbd>Enter</kbd>  to restart the application), ... are stored. You could compare it with a bookmark in your browser which opens a series of tabs.

Having such functionality would drastically reduce the amount of time needed to restore work environments.

By the way, I am aware of the Hibernate functionality in Ubuntu, but this is not what I am looking for. Sometimes, I really have to reboot, unfortunately.

I am using the MATE desktop environment, if that matters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what you need is [`byobu`](http://byobu.co/), install and play around with it you will love it. [Documentation](http://byobu.co/documentation.html).

To install:

- `sudo apt install byobu`

> byobu is a script that launches a text based window manager (either screen(1) or  tmux(1))
>          in  the  byobu  configuration.   This enables the display of system information and status
>          notifications within two lines at the bottom  of  the  screen  session.  It  also  enables
>          multiple tabbed terminal sessions, accessible through simple keystrokes.
>
> byobu  currently  defaults to using tmux(1) (if present) as the backend, however, this can
>          be overridden with the byobu-select-backend(1) utility.

To launch at boot:

- `byobu-enable`

Decide which multiplexer the backend should use:

- byobu-select-backend

  ```
  Select the byobu backend:
     1. tmux
     2. screen

  Choose 1-2 [1]:
  ```

Using sessions [ What your looking for and why I love it]:

> A session is simply a running instance of Byobu. A session consists of a collection of windows, which are basically shell sessions, and panes, which are windows split into multiple sections.
>
> The first time you start Byobu, it starts you a fresh session in which you create windows and panes. On subsequent connections, if you have only one session open, Byobu will automatically open that session when you connect; if you have more than one session open, Byobu will ask you which session you want to use with a prompt like this:

```
Byobu sessions...

  1. tmux: 1: 1 windows (created Wed Aug  3 16:34:26 2016) [80x23]
  2. tmux: 2: 1 windows (created Wed Aug  3 16:34:38 2016) [80x23]
  3. Create a new Byobu session (tmux)
  4. Run a shell without Byobu (/bin/bash)

Choose 1-4 [1]:
```

Checkout this excellent tutorial on byobu from [digitalocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-byobu-for-terminal-management-on-ubuntu-16-04).

Comment: Please add just a little more detail and then refer to the documentation for additional details or perhaps convert this to a comment. As it is now it borders on a link only answer

Comment: That looks promising. Great suggestion George!

Comment: @panther why do have to drive such a hard bargain, will do so ASAP!